# Sign table for a function (math)

Tags: tables

I know I should search for more information, but the more I read the more gets me confused. I just want a simple table with the sign of a function. Something like this one:
[image: Function sign]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%Gummi|065|=)
\title{\textbf{Welcome to Gummi 0.6.6}}

\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c| c c c c c }
 x & $-\infty$ & &1 & & $+\infty$\\ 
 \hline
 $x+1$ &  &- - - - - - - - -& 0 & ++++++++++ \\

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

In my table I cannot put the signs under the infinity. If someone can help me or point me in the right direction I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with simple table:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%Gummi|065|=)
\title{\textbf{Welcome to Gummi 0.6.6}}

\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\[
\begin{array}{ r| l c r}
x   & -\infty           & 1 & +\infty       \\
    \hline
x+1 & - - - - - - - - - & 0 & ++++++++++    \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]